# Clicking a non-clickable button waiting to upload the download to download Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I did an automation on a site to download some files.The problem is, before you click to download the file, the button is not clickable even though it is present in the DOM.Only clicks when downlod upload completes

I use this code to click the button

```
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=15).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDownloadDocumento"]'))).click()
```

i use `sleep ()` with 8 seconds to wait for the button to be clickable

does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDownloadDocumento"]')))
 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnDownloadDocumento"]'))).click()
```